# How to draw detected object with SIFT features on OpenCV 3.1?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, surf

Using this code to find matches between images:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>

#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //cv::initModule_nonfree();
    //initModule_features2d();
    Mat img_1 = imread("C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/0.jpg", 1);
    Mat img_2 = imread("C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/0.jpg", 1);

    cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();

    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints:
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
    f2d->detect(img_1, keypoints_1);
    f2d->detect(img_2, keypoints_2);

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)    
    Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
    f2d->compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
    f2d->compute(img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

    Mat out0;
    drawKeypoints(img_1, keypoints_1, out0);
    imshow("KeyPoint0.jpg", out0);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using BFMatcher :
    BFMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);

    Mat img_matches = Mat::zeros( img_1.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    drawMatches(img_1,keypoints_1,img_2,keypoints_2,matches,img_matches);
    imshow("matches", img_matches);

    waitKey(0);  // Keep window there until user presses 'q' to quit.

    return 0;
}
```

Since `OpenCV 3.1` functions were changed, I looked for example code using `SURF` or `SIFT`, but could not find any.

How to modify this code so it will draw contours around detected objects similar to [`OpenCV version`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `findHomography` to get the transformation that relates your training image (img_1) to the image to be detected (img_2)

Then you can simply do a `perspectiveTransform` on a bounding box of your training image (at origin) using the homography obtained, to place the correct bounding box on the detected image

Related code taken from [ORB detection example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_tracking/akaze_tracking.html)

```
Mat inlier_mask, homography;
vector<KeyPoint> inliers1, inliers2;
vector<DMatch> inlier_matches;
if(matched1.size() >= 4) {
    homography = findHomography(Points(matched1), Points(matched2),
                                RANSAC, ransac_thresh, inlier_mask);
}

for(unsigned i = 0; i < matched1.size(); i++) {
    if(inlier_mask.at<uchar>(i)) {
        int new_i = static_cast<int>(inliers1.size());
        inliers1.push_back(matched1[i]);
        inliers2.push_back(matched2[i]);
        inlier_matches.push_back(DMatch(new_i, new_i, 0));
    }
}
stats.inliers = (int)inliers1.size();
stats.ratio = stats.inliers * 1.0 / stats.matches;

vector<Point2f> new_bb;
perspectiveTransform(object_bb, new_bb, homography);
Mat frame_with_bb = frame.clone();
if(stats.inliers >= bb_min_inliers) {
    drawBoundingBox(frame_with_bb, new_bb);
}
Mat res;
drawMatches(first_frame, inliers1, frame_with_bb, inliers2,
            inlier_matches, res,
            Scalar(255, 0, 0), Scalar(255, 0, 0));
```